# Citing a report with an institutional author

Tags: bibliographies

How would you commonly register a report from an institution in Biblatex like the following:

```
@Report{OUNHCHR2014,
  Title                    = {The right to privacy in the digital age},
  Author                   = {{Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights}},
  Date                     = {2014-06-30},
  Institution              = {Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights},
  Type                     = {Annual report of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights and reports of the Office of the High Commissioner and the Secretary-General},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Location                 = {Geneva, Switzerland},
  Number                   = {A/HRC/27/37},
  Version                  = {2014-06-30}
}
```

Should the issuing institution go in the *Author* or the *Institution* field, or both (as per my example)? Or is this more a question of personal preference or the citation style used?

Comment: I would set the `author` field to `{{United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights}}` and leave the `institution` field as you currently have it. By the way, I wouldn't say the document's author is "unknown". Instead, the document is by a "corporate author"...

Comment: You're right about the "unknown" author @Mico I've edited the question. I'm not sure if "United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights" would be the best choice for the *Author* field though. Wouldn't that suggest that the high commissioner herself (Navi Pillay) is the author?

Comment: Do you have an url for that document? In that kind of report, it happens that the way it should be cited is mentioned, or at least you can get inspiration from the way they cite documents.

Comment: @mritz_p - The only way to make clear that a specific person is an author is to use that specific name. In the case of a corporate author, I believe it's generally understood that the piece was not necessarily penned by the head of that organization.

Comment: Or you could use `author = {{United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights}, Office of}`? I would probably leave `author` as you have it, though.

Comment: @Clément The document is available under http://www.ohchr.org/EN/HRBodies/HRC/RegularSessions/Session27/Documents/A.HRC.27.37_en.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authoritative document is probably

> Garner, Diane L., and Diane H. Smith. *The Complete Guide to Citing Government Documents: A Manual for Writers and Librarians*. 1984.

I am not able to understand if the document you want to cite is

- an official record,
- a resolution,
- a masthead (formerly mimeographed) document,
- none of the above.

Depending on that answer, the [library of Mc Master University](http://library.mcmaster.ca/govpubs/cite#Sample_Citations_-_United_Nations_Documents) and the [United Nations Editorial Manual Online](http://dd.dgacm.org/editorialmanual/ed-guidelines/footnotes/footnotes_chap_03.htm)  gives recommendations.
For instance, for a Masthead document :

> Name of main U.N. body, session (if one). Subsidiary body, session (if one). Title spacer(Document number). day month year of publication. (Document type i.e. Masthead or spacerMimeo). (Notes,i.e. microform collection note).

In the [Brief Guide to Citing Government Publications](http://www.memphis.edu/govpub/citweb.php) of the University of Memphis, and in the [How to cite OUN documents](http://www.bournemouth.ac.uk/library/how-to/un-doc.html) of the Bournemouth University, the do not mention anything that could correspond to your institution field.

You should probably also have a look at [that source](http://brs.newsbank.com/ihelp/english/UNAD/how2cite.html) to make up your mind, but I would say that :

**tl;dr: Surprisingly enough, I would leave the `institution` field empty and gives as an author `{{U.N. High Commissioner for Human Rights}}`.**

**I think the [United Nations Editorial Manual Online](http://dd.dgacm.org/editorialmanual/ed-guidelines/footnotes/footnotes_chap_03.htm)  is the best resource to find your answer.**

But I'm afraid some tweaking might be necessary for some styles.

---

(As a side not, I would add an `url` field pointing to http://www.ohchr.org/EN/Issues/DigitalAge/Pages/DigitalAgeIndex.aspx in your entry.)